# Funcion asincronica en javascript

Tags: javascript, variables-globales, asincronismo, const

Este es el codigo, no puedo utilizar el dato retornado fuera del bloque, es decir no puedo utilizar en otra variable ni imprimirlo fuera del mismo

```
async function obtenerDatos(callback){
        try {
            const respuesta = await fetch(URL);
            const datos = await respuesta.json();
            return datos.filter(palabra => palabra.length == 5);
          } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
          }
    };
obtenerDatos(datos=>{
  console.log(datos)
)
```

Comment: Qué variable quieres utilizar fuera de qué bloque??

Answer (score 0):

por lo que veo en el fragmento de código que has puesto supongo que es problema de sincronía, lo que te podria sugerir y que probablemente te ayude a solucionarlo es usar `promesas`.

La razón por la que no puedes usar la información afuera de tu función probablemente es que no está esperando que termine de realizar la petición para usar la información, por ende no obtiene respuesta y ya está intentando usarla.

En el ejemplo de abajo te muestro un ejemplo de como deberías usar promesas para que espere la respuesta, es una funcion muy similar a la que usas tu y la dejo en un snnipet para que puedas ejecutarla.

Y aca dejo información relacionada que puede servirte

[Recurso aprendizaje de sincrono, asincrono](https://www.freecodecamp.org/espanol/news/sincrono-vs-asincrono-en-javascript/)

[Recurso acerca de promesas](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises)

```js
function obtenerDatos(username){
      return fetch(`//api.github.com/users/${username}`)
      .then(response => {
        return response.json()
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
      })
}

//Asi lo haces acutalmente, mostrara un arreglo vacio.
//No espera a que se termine de realizar la peticion
console.log("Obteniendo datos sincrono", obtenerDatos("david081"))


obtenerDatos("david081").then(res=>{
  //espera a que la peticion responda sin errores para ejecutar esta logica
  console.log(res)
}).catch(error=>{
  //espera por si la peticion responde con error para mostrar esto.
  console.log(error)
})
```